# why i am getting electron builder codesign error

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron-builder, electronic-signature

I have below settings for co-design through pfx file and password. I don't know why do I need subjectName here. and why I am getting this error. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `./` to the `certificateFile` value

`"./build/wild......"`

This look for build directory from the current directory.

Comment: used "certificateFile":"./build/wildcard_production_imsglobal_com.pfx",

still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

i am using SSL for code signing, i need CSR for sign my exe. This type of CSR is available on DigiCert website. They have utility tool.